# Are external commands started by powershell scripts run synchrously or asynchrously as background processes?

Tags: powershell

If I were to start an exteral program from a powershell script and then start another one, does the first program started wait to exit before running the next command?

For example:

```
 # Assume pagent loaded our key...
 & {
      & pscp -sftp "<some-path>\text*.json" nonroot@somehost:/home/nonroot/json ;
      Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE;
      & plink nonroot@somehost  "/bin/processJSON.sh /home/nonroot/json";
      Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE;
  }
```

Comment: If the external program is a console-subsystem application (a command-line utility), it will indeed run synchronously when started by name/path/ `&` / `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, PowerShell will always wait synchronously for a console application to complete. For Win32 applications, if the output of the command is not redirected, then the command will run asynchronously. If it is redirected, then PowerShell will wait for the command to complete. For example, running `notepad` from the command line will start notepad running asynchronously with PowerShell but if you ran `notepad | out-null` then PowerShell would wait until the notepad process exited before proceeding. On Linux or MacOS, there is no OS distinction between "windows" and "non-windows" applications so PowerShell always waits for the child process to complete. So unless the application puts itself in to the background (which a lot of GUI tools do), on these platforms you have to explicitly run the process as a background job using `&` e.g. `xedit &`.